# AngularJS Promise & atop Filter. Failed to execute 'atob' on 'Window'

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, promise, angular-promise

**Background:** Working on Angular front ends. Retrieving a document that is base64 encoded from a backend. atob is giving me an error, but everything works.

**Suspicion:** I think my atob filter is called twice. Hitting the promise while the variable is undefined/null and then after the promise fills the variable.

**Filter Code**:

```
angular.module('docFilters', []).filter('base64Decode', function() {
    return function(cipherText) {
        return atob(cipherText);
    };
});
```

**Controller Code**:

```
angular.module('doc')
    .controller('DocCtrl', ['$scope', 'DocService', function ($scope, DocService) {   
        $scope.doc = DocService.getCurrentDoc();    
    }]);
```

getCurrentDoc() is a REST request. It makes a GET request to an internal web service.

**Html**:

```
<span ng-bind-html="doc.content | base64Decode"></span>
```

This works 'fine' - without checking the console you would never know. The console shows:

"Error: Failed to execute 'atob' on 'Window': The string to be decoded is not correctly encoded."

This is new for me, so I'm not sure if there is a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`atob(undefined); //throws an error`

You need to modify you filter

```
angular.module('docFilters', []).filter('base64Decode', function() {
    return function(text) {
        return text && atob(text);
    };
});
```

Comment: I went with this one. 

Maybe because I'm new but that just looked elegant and is the kind of code that brought me back to programming over systems. 

Is this similar to a ternary operator? Take the text until the variable is filled by the promise and then decode the ciphertext?

Comment: @HayekSplosives `A && B` essentially means "if A then B else A".

Comment: @HayekSplosives It works due to the "laziness" of `&&` operator. Consider `A && B` if `A` is falsy you don't need to evaluate `B`, otherwise you need to check if `B` is truthy. You can rewrite it using ternary operator `return A ? B : A`.

Answer (score 1):

Why not have the filter check whether there's a value?

```
angular.module('docFilters', []).filter('base64Decode', function() {
    return function(cipherText) {
        if (cipherText) {
            return atob(cipherText);
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Because I'm still new enough I don't know how to do that. I understand the concept but not the implementation. Ty!